# .setText() being called but screen not updateing while in a while(true) loop

Tags: java, android

I've been running into this bug and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it as I'm fairly new to java and android development so I would really appreciate any help I could get with this!

The bug I'm running into is that when I'm using `.setText()` to update a `TextView` element periodically the text displayed on screen never actually changes.

I believe this is due to the while(true) loop in the `startCrunching()` method I'm using to run the main calculation process as before I start that method the screen updates fine with the test data I'm feeding it.

I also know that when the while loop starts the `updateScreen()` method is only being called from the while loop and not the repeating handler I have as the handler stops posting logs to the logcat when the method starts but then the while loop logs start being posted.

What I want to achieve is the while(true) loop running as quickly as possible while every so often (as a variable of time and not cycles of the while loop) updating the screen with information regarding the process in the while loop.

I know the while loop is running and the `updateScreen()` method is being called.

Full source below:

```
package com.example.android.collatzconjecturepathcruncher;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView longestPathDisplay;
    TextView longestPathSeedDisplay;
    TextView currentSeedDisplay;
    EditText startingNumberDisplay;

    BigInteger longestPathSeed= BigInteger.ONE;
    int longestPath=0;
    BigInteger currentSeed=BigInteger.ZERO;
    int currentPath=0;
    BigInteger workingSeed=BigInteger.ONE;
    boolean run;

    int temp =0;

    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        longestPathDisplay = findViewById(R.id.longest_path);
        longestPathSeedDisplay = findViewById(R.id.longest_path_seed);
        currentSeedDisplay = findViewById(R.id.current_seed_display);
        startingNumberDisplay = findViewById(R.id.starting_number_display);

        longestPathDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_display,longestPath));
        longestPathSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_seed_display,longestPathSeed));
        currentSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.current_seed_display,currentSeed));

        mHandler = new Handler();
        startRepeatingTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        stopRepeatingTask();
    }

    public void startCrunching(View view){

        String value = startingNumberDisplay.getText().toString();
        currentSeed = new BigInteger(value);

        workingSeed=currentSeed;

        run=true;

        while(run){

            if(workingSeed.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==0){

                if(currentPath>longestPath){
                    longestPath=currentPath;
                    longestPathSeed=currentSeed;
                }
                currentSeed= currentSeed.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                workingSeed=currentSeed;
                Log.d("end", "startCrunching: Finished "+(currentSeed.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))+" at "+currentPath+". Starting "+currentSeed);
                currentPath=0;
                updateScreen();
            }

            if (workingSeed.mod(new BigInteger("2")).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0){
                workingSeed=workingSeed.divide(new BigInteger("2"));
            }else{
                workingSeed=(workingSeed.multiply(new BigInteger("3"))).add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
            currentPath++;
        }

    }

    public void updateScreen() {

        //longestPathDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_display, longestPath));
        //longestPathSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_seed_display, longestPathSeed));
        //currentSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.current_seed_display, currentSeed));

        longestPathDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_display, temp));
        longestPathSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.longest_path_seed_display, temp));
        currentSeedDisplay.setText(getString(R.string.current_seed_display, temp));
        Log.d("update","requested screen update. Temp currently: "+temp);
        temp++;
    }

    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                updateScreen();
                Log.d("repeat","Tried Updating Screen");
            }finally {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker,5000);
            }
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask(){
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!
-Michael

Comment: Debug the loop .. while true will run in fractions of seconds and you will only see the last updated value .is that what you want ??

Comment: No, that updateScreen() call was only for debugging purposes I want that function to  only be called once every 5 seconds which I have it doing before the while loop begins. I put the call in the loop just so I could check that the problem wasn't that the function wasn't getting called, which turned out to also be an issue for some reason once the loop begins.

Comment: where are you setting the "run" variable to false? It's a bit late for me, but the while loop is never stoped from what i can see in your code.

Comment: You are correct, the while loop doesn't stop currently, eventually once I work this bug out I will just add a button to the UI that will call a method to set it to false. Is it not possible to have the UI update while the while loop is still running?

Comment: run=true; is setted up!! it's didn't setted to false, so the loop never ends and leads to Infinite loop. All the process in the screen may got struck due to this infinity loop and at the same time Handler also running infinitely till Destroying the activity... Seriously it leads to the process delays or process hangouts.

Comment: Is there no way to have the `.setText()` commands actually update while the loop is still running? The handler seems to stop on it's own too when the while loop begins for some reason. Can I not have both of them running at the same time?

Comment: Since you running while(true) at UI thread, it will update just at the end. The solution is to use a Thread to fire events to a Handler (or just a Handler relaunching a message delayed to itself).

Comment: So I should create a thread to run the while loop in? I'm pretty new to threads, so details would be really appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed it, but I Don't see where you actual call your crunchnumber method.

Comment: It is tied to be called by an onClick event in the .xml file.
    `android:onClick="startCrunching"`

Answer (score 0):

`startCrunching()` this method is never called. I guess you need to change you execution sequence

Comment: "It is tied to be called by an onClick event in the .xml file. `android:onClick="startCrunching"` "